# ink_env::ecdsa_recover is not returning the right public key

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, hash, ecdsa

I am having an issue trying to verify ecdsa signature in ink! for my
test.

I am generating the signature this way

```
const keyring = new Keyring({type: 'ecdsa'});
const pair =  keyring.addFromUri('//Alice');
```

Then i get the public key to be stored in the contract storage as the governor during instantiation of the contract

```
const publicKey = pair.publicKey;
```

This is how i am signing the message(data)

```
const sig = Array.from(pair.sign(hashDataArray));
```

Then i pass the signature into the contract.

But when i call `ink_env::ecdsa_recover` in the contract to recover the public key from the signature, i get a different public key entirely different from the one i stored(generated) in the contract during instantiation.

Comment: Does your signature verify on [PolkadotJS](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/signing/verify)? The signature creation in the [Docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/keyring/start/sign-verify/#using-known-pairs) looks like its using the data and not the hash. Anyway, please consider sharing the code which makes it much easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured the signature creation in polkadotJS is to receive the raw data and not the hash.

More so, I had to generate the public key this way:

```
const mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate();
const keyring = new Keyring({type: 'ethereum'});
const pair = keyring.addFromUri(mnemonic, { name: 'first pair' }, 'ethereum');
      
const publicKey = pair.publicKey;
```

And then i created the signature this way

```
const sig = Array.from(pair.sign(rawData));
```

With this generation, I was able to recover the public key successfully with `ink_env::ecdsa_recover`

N.B: I am using `keccak256` for hashing. The Keyring type `ecdsa` uses `blake2` for hashing hence why I used the type `ethereum` which uses keccak for hashing. You can find the details [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/common/blob/3597a4eb4e0cf9985104568058c5cd23701bbaed/packages/keyring/src/pair/index.ts#L37)